# Creating a JWT using EdDSA/Ed25519 algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, jwt, eddsa

I want to create a JWT usnig EdDSA algorithm.
The key pair is generated by a different module. I need to read the private key from file and sign the JWT using it.

The claim will contain a custom entry along with iat and jti.

I am able to write it in python with the Cryptography package, but as I am new to C++, need some help here.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on _why_ would you do that. For C++, there are more seasoned, robust and widespread key formats. Would you like to create some server-side service? Have to interoperate with browser/JS stuff?

Comment: Its for a IoT product that communicates with the server. The server knows the public key. The requirement is to create a JWT using the private key (created using EdDSA algo) that is alresdy available with the device. and use it in header of for API calls